# Date logic suggestion

Tags: apex, visualforce, validation-rule, error-messages

In my leave management module i am applying error messages for below conditions-

```
if(w.le.Start_Date__c >w.le.End_Date__c){
   counter++;                    
   ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.Error,'End Date should be greater than or equal to Start Date'));
}
if(w.le.End_Date__c<system.TODAY()){
   counter++;                    
   ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.Error,'End Date should be greater than or equal to Today'));
}
if(w.le.Start_Date__c <system.TODAY()){
   counter++;                    
   ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.Error,'Start Date should be greater than or equal to Today'));   
}
```

what if i dont want my user to select in between dates of already submitted start date and end date.
Suppose i applied leave for start date: 19/01/2017 to end date: 21/01/2017
Then again if i apply for leave, error message should display if i choose start date: 18/01/2017

What should i do for this?

Comment: you will first need to fetch the leaves already in the system. Then compare the new leave with those existing leaves.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to enforce that date ranges do not overlap is to abuse [Custom Types in Map Keys and Sets](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_collections_maps_keys_userdefined.htm). If you have every instance of your key type return a `hashCode` of `1`, then you can use the `equals` function to evaluate overlap.

Here's a minimal script you can run via `Execute Anonymous` to demonstrate the concept:

```
class DateRange
{
    final Date startDate, endDate;
    DateRange(Date startDate, Date endDate)
    {
        this.startDate = startDate;
        this.endDate = endDate;
    }
    public Integer hashCode() { return 1; }
    public Boolean equals(Object instance)
    {
        DateRange that = (DateRange)instance;
        Boolean containsStartDate = that.startDate >= startDate &&
            that.startDate <= endDate;
        Boolean containsEndDate = that.endDate >= startDate &&
            that.endDate <= endDate;
        return containsStartDate || containsEndDate;
    }
}

Set<DateRange> ranges = new Set<DateRange>
{
    new DateRange(
        Date.newInstance(2017,1,17),
        Date.newInstance(2017,1,21)
    )
};

system.assert(ranges.contains(new DateRange(
    Date.newInstance(2017,1,18),
    Date.newInstance(2017,2,1)
)));
```

So you can incorporate a key type like this `DateRange` class to enforce that none of your leave ranges overlap.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to create a boolean test condition along the lines of the following where `old.w.le.Start_Date__c` and  `old.w.le.End_Date__c` represent the existing values for the Start and End dates.

```
if((w.le.Start_Date__c > old.w.le.Start_Date__c) && (w.le.Start_Date__c < old.w.le.End_Date__c)) {

ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.Error,('New Start Date cannot be between Existing Start Date and End Date'))
}

if((w.le.End_Date__c > old.w.le.Start_Date__c) && (w.le.End_Date__c < old.w.le.End_Date__c)) {
ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.Error,('New End Date cannot be between Existing Start Date and End Date'))
}
```